# how do i continue on breakpoint in gdb automatically

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, kernel, breakpoints

I'm debugging my linux kernel module. It causes deadlock and i'm trying to figure out how. I'm using `vmware` + `gdb`. The idea is to hook the function and log backtrace into the file. I'm trying the following:

```
(gdb) br _raw_spin_lock
Breakpoint 5 at 0xffffffff815eb700: file kernel/spinlock.c, line 136.
(gdb) commands 5
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 5, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>silent
>bt
>continue
>end
```

but `continue` doesn't work here. If i replace `bt` with `echo 1` it works. Is there way to log information every time the function is called?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at here [GDB continuing and stepping](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_6.html#SEC37)

Comment: doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are hitting gdb pagination prompt.
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html

Run this before setting the breakpoint

```
set height 0
```

Comment: `set pagination off` is perhaps a little bit more intuitive than `set height 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why it doesn't work.  What exactly goes wrong?

Normally this kind of thing works fine.  Putting "continue" into a breakpoint's commands is something I've done routinely for years.  It isn't without problems (it interferes with "next") but if you are just doing logging or the like, it works great.

One guess would be that the "bt" is failing with an error.  This would cause the commands to abort and, I believe, the inferior to stop at the breakpoint.  Then the question is, what exact error message is emitted?  Or perhaps you're hitting pagination.  Or maybe some other thing I haven't thought of :-)

If it's an error, one possible option might be to limit the backtrace.

Comment: Can confirm, `continue` after a `bt` works in the breakpoint commands list, as expected (GDB 7.12.1 on Fedora 25). There are limitations with other breakpoint commands - e.g. a command like `finish` ends the execution of a commands list.